# Criar uma classe só de comandos

Tags: c#

Eu criei uma classe só de comandos, até ai tudo bem, puxei a classe de comandos para a classe principal mas eu estou com um erro

Classe de comandos:

```
public bool OnCommand(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 1)
    {
        string a;
        if ((a = args[1]) != null)
        {
            if (a == "teste")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("teste");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Classe Principal (Coloquei só uma parte do código, achei desnecessario a outra parte):

```
public void OnAction(Hashtable parameters)
{
      cmd.OnCommand();
}
```

Obs: estou com erro nesta parte: `cmd.OnCommand();` diz: Não há nenhum argumento fornecido que corresponde ao parâmetro formal necessário "args"

Comment: `args` provem de onde ? mostra o codigo.

Comment: amigo sou novo em c#, não entendi oque voce disse

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente `args` é uma string e não um `array` de strings tenta passar desta forma:

```
cmd.OnCommand(new string[] { "ArgumentoUm", "ArgumentoDois", "ArgumentoTres" } )
```

Se quiseres, Acrescenta *params*:

```
 public bool OnCommand(params string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 1)
            {
                string a;
                if ((a = args[1]) != null)
                {
                    if (a == "teste")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("teste");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Assim poderás chamar a função sem passar uma nova string assim:

```
cmd.OnCommand("ArgumentoUm", "ArgumentoDois", "ArgumentoTres" )
```

Comment: Mas queria que tipo, quando eu digitasse teste no console, iria escrever teste, no caso eu fiz oque voce disse e não apareceu

Comment: se `ArgumentoDois` for `teste` irá apareçer, i guess

Comment: no caso seria assim? teste teste?

Comment: `cmd.OnCommand("ArgumentoUm", "teste", "ArgumentoTres" )` mas lembrate que tens de ter `params` a frente do paramentro da função `OnCommand` editei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado funcionou, mas não tem como retirar o teste que você escreve e fica registrado, e tem como criar uma verificação se o comando existe?

Comment: primeiramente mostra a variável que queres passar como parâmetro, de onde ela provem? `args =`, igual a que ?

Comment: se voce está dizendo desse cmd.OnCommand(args); eu tinha colocado errado, estava sem o args